# Understanding xarray.apply_ufunc

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-xarray

I have an xarray with multiple time dimensions `slow_time`, `fast_time` a dimension representing different objects `object` and a dimension reflecting the position of each object at each point in time `coords`.

The goal is now to apply a rotation using `scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation` to each position in this array, for every point in time.

I'm struggling to figure out how to use `xarray.apply_ufunc` to do what I want, mainly because the concept of `input_core_dimensions` isn't really clear to me.

The code below shows what I'm trying to do:

```py
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation

# dummy initial positions
initial_position = xr.DataArray(np.arange(6).reshape((-1,3)), dims=["object", "coords"])
# dummy velocities
velocity = xr.DataArray(np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 0.5, 0]]), dims=["object", "coords"])

slow_time = xr.DataArray(np.linspace(0, 1, 10, endpoint=False), dims=["slow_time"])
fast_time = xr.DataArray(np.linspace(0, 0.1, 100, endpoint=False), dims=["fast_time"])

# times where to evaluate my function
times = slow_time + fast_time

# this is the data I want to transform
positions = times * velocity + initial_position

# these are the rotation angles
theta = np.pi/20 * times
phi = np.pi/100 * times

def apply_rotation(vectors, theta, phi):
    R = Rotation.from_euler("xz", (theta, phi))
    result = R.apply(vectors)
    return result

rotated_positions = xr.apply_ufunc(apply_rotation,
    positions, theta, phi, ...??)
```

The behaviour I'm looking for is essentially like four nested for loops that apply the rotations to each point like this pseudocode

```py
for pos, t, p in zip(positions, theta, phi):
    R = Rotation.from_euler("xz", (t, p))
    R.apply(pos)
```

But I'm unsure how to proceed.

Using this

```py
rotated_positions = xr.apply_ufunc(apply_rotation,
    positions, theta, phi,
    input_core_dims=[["object"],[],[]], output_core_dims=[["object"]])
```

I thought the function would be applied along subarrays of the `object` dimension, but now I get entire arrays passed into my function which doesn't work.

The information on `apply_ufunc` in the xarray documentation doesn't really makes things very clear.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I have a similar problem in that I want to apply a coordinate transform to a 3D data array of 3-vectors. For now I've circumvented this by applying the transform manually to the underlying NumPy array and re-wrapping it into xarray - but I'd like to use `apply_ufunc` or the like to speed this up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Reference

First off, a helpful reference would be [this documentation page on unvectorized ufunc](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/apply_ufunc_vectorize_1d.html)

### Solution

As I understand your question you want to apply a rotation to the position vector of each object at every time.
The way you have set up your data already puts the coordinates as the final dimension of the array.

Translating your pseudocode to generate a reference dataset `rotatedPositions` yields:

```
rotatedPositions = positions.copy()
for slowTimeIdx in range( len(slow_time)):
    for fastTimeIdx in range( len(fast_time) ):
        for obj in range(2):
            pos = rotatedPositions.data[slowTimeIdx, fastTimeIdx, obj].copy()
            rotatedPositions.data[slowTimeIdx, fastTimeIdx, obj] =  apply_rotation(pos, theta.data[slowTimeIdx, fastTimeIdx], phi.data[slowTimeIdx, fastTimeIdx])
```

where I hard-coded the `object` dimension size.

In essence the `apply_rotation` function takes 1 3-vector (1D array of size 3) and 2 scalars and returns a 1D array of size 3 (3 vector).

Following the documentation mentioned above I arrive at the following call to `apply_ufunc`:

```
rotated = xr.apply_ufunc(apply_rotation, 
               positions,
                theta,
                phi,
               input_core_dims=[['coords'], [], []],
               output_core_dims=[['coords']],
               vectorize=True
              )
```

Testing via

```
np.allclose(rotatedPositions.data, rotated.data)
```

indicates success.

### Explanation

As I understand the documentation cited above `apply_ufunc` will take the function to be applied as first argument, then all positional arguments in order.

Next one has to provide the dimension labels of each dataset that will correspond to the data that will be `core` to `apply_rotation` working. Here this is `coords`, as we manipulate coordinates. Since neither `theta` nor `phi` have this dimension we do not specify anything for them.

Next we have to specify the dimensions the output data will have, since we just transform the output data we keep `output_core_dims=[['coords']]`. Leaving this out would lead `apply_ufunc` to assume output data to be 0-dimensional (a scalar).

Finally,`vectorize=True` ensures that the function is executed over all dimensions *not* specified in `input_core_dims`.

Comment: Hi Nox, thank you for your explanation, clearly outlining the relationships between the `input_core_dims`, `output_core_dims` and `vectorize` arguments to `apply_ufunc`.